# Transit visa for Dubai for females

Tags: dubai

I have individual flights from Bucharest to DXB (arrival in T2 at 6.55 am with FlyDubai) and then DXB to Jaipur (India) (departure from T2 at 9.55 am the next morning with Air India).

I'm a 20-year old female, a student with a Romanian residence visa, traveling alone, and my transit is over 24 hours.

Do I need a transit visa for this? Or is there a transfer desk that will check in my luggage and I will get my Air India boarding pass in the transit area? (Can I do a web check in, and just stay in the transit area if I don't have check-in baggage?)

Comment: Why a downvote?

Comment: What is your citizenship?  That's more relevant than your residency or visa status.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are an Indian National, you are not on the [list](https://www.visitdubai.com/en/travel-planning/travel-tools/visa-and-entry-information) of countries with Visa on Arrival. The same site says that you can arrange a 96-hour transit visa *with the airline,* which I suspect means that you do not have to stay in the airport. I suggest contacting FlyDubai to find out how to get this visa.

There are special rules in the Gulf Countries about unaccompanied young women from Russia and other former USSR countries, but as far as I know, they do not apply to India, nor to Romania (Romanians are entitled to visa on arrival).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I have an Indian passport. I asked the Dubai embassy in Romania and they said that i would need to be accompanied by my parents or an adult (and my parents transfer my power of attorney to him) to get a visa. I cannot call the UAE embassy in India since I can't call them.  I was wondering if i just skip the visa altogether and stay in the transit area, will i get my Air India boarding passes in the transit zone? (I will change the first FlyDubai flight and make the layover time 13 hours)